# Javascript function in associative array not working

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the following to return the appropriate key but keep getting only 9. Help and thank you.

```
var strZip = "96161";

var regionCodes = {
4: '00501',    
4: '00544',    
4: '06390',    
2: '96161',    
2: '96162',
getKey: function(value){
    for(var key in this){
        if(this[key] == value){
            return key;
        }
    }
    return 9; // Default 9 if not found
    }
};

var zipKey = regionCodes.getKey(strZip);
```

---

I've also tried (and failed) with the variation that reads:

```
getKey: function(value){
    for(var key in this){
        if( this.hasOwnProperty( key) ) {
            if(this[key] === value){
                return key;
            }
        }
    }
    return 9; // Default 9 if not found
}
```

Comment: The second `2: '96162'` overwrites the first one. You can't have multiple "values" on the same "key"

Comment: Your code shows an object with duplicate property names.

Comment: You should either revert the map (having your values as keys) or use an array.

Comment: js does not have _associative array_, so when you define literal object - js no _push_ every property, but override same key with last value

Comment: It's worth mentioning that Ecmascript 6 will actually support duplicate object keys, for some reason.

Comment: @JeremyThille can you show where it, i mean link? it interesting how get values for that key :-) Or you mean support: not raise exception in strict mode?

Comment: Argh, I can't find it back. I saw a post on stackoverflow yesterday, precisely about "what's the advantage of supporting duplicate object keys in ES6?", I'm searching the post

Comment: Oh, here it is : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30617139/whats-the-purpose-of-allowing-duplicate-property-names/30617831#30617831

Comment: @JeremyThille, so by link say that anyway you can get only last defined value, or i something missed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have identical keys `{4:,4:,4:,2:,2:}` in your object. Try making the keys unique **or** change your approach like in Andys answer.

Otherwise, it will only work if the value happens to be of the first key in the object

```js
var strZip = "96161";

var regionCodes = {
1: '00501',    
2: '00544',    
3: '06390',    
4: '96161',    
5: '96162',
getKey: function(value){
    for(var key in this){
        if(this[key] == value){
            return key;
        }
    }
    return 9; // Default 9 if not found
    }
};

var zipKey = regionCodes.getKey(strZip);
console.log(zipKey);
```

**Or** use `key -> array` with `indexOf()` like

```js
var strZip = "961261";

var regionCodes = {
4: ['00501', '00544',  '06390'],
2: ['96161', '96162'],
getKey: function(value){
    for(var key in this){
        if(typeof(this[key]) != 'function' && this[key].indexOf(value) > -1){
            return key;
        }
    }
    return 9; // Default 9 if not found
    }
};

var zipKey = regionCodes.getKey(strZip);
console.log(zipKey);
```

Comment: would love an explanation for the downvote, pretty please? :)

Comment: Because it appears the actual keys are important otherwise the OP wouldn't have tried to specify more than one. You're returning the wrong keys. For example, you're returning `1` not `4`.

Comment: @Andy, OP said 'I'm trying to get the following to return the appropriate key but keep getting only 9.'... I explained why he is getting 9. If the actual keys are important he will need to try another approach such as your answer. I changed the keys to show his error, thats all

Comment: And you said: "Try making the keys unique." and that's not what the OP apparently wants.

Comment: @Andy, in which I said thereafter **Otherwise**, it will only work if the value happens to be of the first key in the object. Anyways, I appreciate your input, even if its a downvote. I was just concerned there may be something technically incorrect with my answer

Comment: Yes, that works! You-all were right in that I was duplicating keys and that the keys are important. I just need to re-structure things accordingly. Though the suggestion to reverse the keys and values would probably work too. Thank you all!!!

Comment: Actually, another problem now. If the value is found - no problem - but if it isn't, the value of 9 is not being returned. I tried changing "function (value)" to "function (value,def=9)" and then "return def" but it failed. I tried a routine after the var zipKey statement that checks for null and sets zipKey to 9 but that didn't work either. I modified the null routine to check for a range <1 or > 4 (the values returned from a successful check) and THAT didn't work either. How to get a return of 9 if the search doesn't succeed?

Comment: @OzzyO, what was happening is it was iterating through all properties of the object including the function. When it got to the function, it gave an exception of undefined indexOf for the function. If you check that you are not at the function l ike I did, you should be fine. Let me know if you need further assistance

Comment: AmmarCSE - Now I understand what's going on. Everything works fine. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the keys are important and, unlike the other answers suggest, they are actually needed in the form you've put in your question, put your keys/codes in an array instead using an object for each group. Then you can use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on the array to pluck out the correct key based on the code provided:

```
var regionCodes = {

    codes: [{
        key: 4, code: '00501'
    }, {
        key: 4, code: '00544'
    }, {
        key: 4, code: '06390'
    }, {
        key: 2, code: '96161'
    }, {
        key: 2, code: '96162'
    }],

    getKey: function (value) {
        var arr = this.codes.filter(function (el) {
            return el.code === value;
        });
        return arr.length ? arr[0].key : 9;
    }
};
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rx9nLf94/1/)