# UI-Grid : Error "Multiple definitions of a property not allowed in strict mode [object Object]" [ IE- Only ]

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

While loading Ui-Grid  In IE throwing error messages -

```
[true]  [SYSERR] Multiple definitions of a property not allowed in strict mode [object Object]
```

[image]
Issue is only in IE, Not throwing any errors in FireFox & Chrome. Tested on IE Version-11.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: why does this only happen on internet explorer?

Answer (score 10):

As the error state, you are using somewhere an object that has more than one property with the same name .
Something like :

```
var obj= {
    property1: 0,
    property2: 1,
    property1: 2
};
```

Printing the upper object results in :

```
{ property1: 2, property2: 1 }
```

Also searching a little bit on stack overflow, you can find a more detailed answer why this error is outputed in Internet Explorer

[What's the purpose of allowing duplicate property names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30617139/whats-the-purpose-of-allowing-duplicate-property-names)

Answer (score 7):

Its difficult to find multiple definition manually when you have long code written by someone else.

I used http://jshint.com/ and pasted code there, it showed me all duplicate  warnings and I fixed those everything worked.

Comment: Link-only answers are highly discouraged here because the links may become dead in the future. I suggest you edit your answer with quotes from the sources you cite.

Comment: @AnirudhSharma I understand links may become dead my answer is just a suggestion how i solved this problem when i faced it, may help someone else they can use some other tools also just giving them a idea here.

Comment: Thanks your hint saved me - was having great trouble finding that double definition. Definitely was worth posting it here!