# Website is not working on IE - SCRIPT1046

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I was editting template for my friend just to make her some website presentation, but for some reason the website is not working on IE or older versions of Mozzila.

I can see that console in IE is throwing these errors:

```
"SCRIPT1046: Několik definic vlastnosti není povoleno v režimu strict."
"main.js (208,16)"
```

I'm talking about [www.meranti.cz](http://www.meranti.cz). Can someone guide me a bit?

Comment: `Multiple definitions of a property not allowed in strict mode` - you have an object literal with the same property defined more than once - it's probably on line 208 in main.js

Comment: yep `itemsTablet: [786,3], itemsTablet: [767,2],` there it is - incredible how the error message points to the exact line and reason for the error ... now why isn't this breaking in Firefox/Chrum/Edge? because `strict mode` seems to have relaxed this limitation in browsers that are constantly being updated (unlike internet explorer)

Comment: see [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30617139/whats-the-purpose-of-allowing-duplicate-property-names)