# Can you overwrite a property in the definition of an object literal without mutating data?

Tags: javascript

In the redux docs on immutable update patterns I've noticed they said that you can update objects by using the spread operator and then overwriting a property.

Is there something special about the object spread operator? If not, then why can you overwrite a property in the definition of an object literal (like in the code below) without mutating data?

```
const a = {
  foo: 'bar',
  foo: 'bla'
}
```

Comment: It's not clear how `...` spread syntax is relevant to the object literal syntax that accepts multiple similar keys.

Comment: "why can you overwrite" --- because the standard allows that.

Comment: Having an object with duplicate keys is a mistake that your linter should catch. (This doesn't even work in older browsers, they only allowed this as of ES6 because they didn't know how deal with computed properties otherwise).

Comment: "*you can update objects by using the spread operator*" - No! The spread syntax is part of an object literal, which *creates a new object*.

Comment: @Bergi https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5 was it actually forbidden before es2015?

Comment: @zerkms Yes: "*If previous is not undefined then throw a SyntaxError exception …*" from that section. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30617139/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi yep, I suspected the section you referred to but am not qualified enough to understand all the internal properties they access there. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In object literals we can use the spread operator (...) it inserts properties from a given object, to the object literal...
so if you have:

```
const a = {
  foo: 'bar',
  test: 'test'
}
```

A new object can be created using the spread operator in the object literal definition..

```
const b = {
   ...a, //spread operator that introduces object properties
   foo:'bla'
}
```

The b object would be

```
{ foo: 'bla', test: 'test' }
```

Take in to account that the if two properties have the same name, the order will define which one takes priority **and indeed we can overwrite a property definition in the object literal.**

if the definition was:

```
const b = {
   foo:'bla',
   ...a, //the spread operator is defined at the end
}
```

The b object will be:

```
{foo: "bar", test: "test"}
```

Refer to [this article](http://2ality.com/2016/10/rest-spread-properties.html)

**Note:** This is a ES2018 proposal, currently working in chrome..