# Efficiently find duplicate data property in object literal?

Tags: ecmascript-6, duplicates, syntax-error, babeljs, object-literal

After creating our new system in Vue with babel, I have started testing compatibility towards older devices. Our babel is transpiling the source down to es2015 together with webpack.

I have now tested with [browserstack](http://www.browserstack.com) against both Ios & android. Newer OS works on both platforms. However on android phones that use the default browser, [I get an error in sentry](https://sentry.io/share/issue/80b575ddcf0842209083b1fa3c712b25/) stating; **`Duplicate data property in object literal not allowed in strict mode`** It does not give me any hints on where this might be thus making the debugging process painfully hard.

The only light in the end of the tunnel I can se now is the ios part. Ios devices that run IOS < 9 states an error **`Attempted to redefine property 'value'.`** [also in sentry](https://sentry.io/share/issue/04ad35e80e054bb7a5243e2409f8537c/)

If I am not mistaking, the ios issue is a reworded error of the same issue?
As I read [over here](http://codersblock.com/blog/javascript-strict-mode/), I suppose 'value' might be defined twice in a object or element.

This all wraps up to the question, how does one go with finding duplicate data properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find out what line the error occurred on and found out that a plugin that I used with name [Vue-numeric](https://github.com/kevinongko/vue-numeric) had created a duplicate value:

```
 domProps: {
   value: n.value,
   value: n.amount
 },
```

I had accidentally locked the plugin on a older version where this problem was present. The issue was fixed by simply updating.

Thank you @xenetics for taking your time on this issue.

Comment: Glad you found it either way! Retuning a function from `data` is generally a good practise either way, even if it wasn't the problem here.

Answer (score 2):

Can you share some of your code (just the  area from a few components?)

One thing to check is inside of `data()`, ensure you are returning an object. This happened to me when I started out with Vue.

Example:

```
// component a
data () {
  a: ''
}

// component b 
data () {
  a: '' // ERROR! Duplicate
}
```

This happens because the `data` is merged on the main Vue instance. So in this case it should look like:

```
// component a
data () {
  return {
    a: ''
  }
}

// component b 
data () {
  return {
    a: '' // ok now
  }
}
```

Hard to make any other guesses without some code.

Comment: I understand that looking at the code wold make this easier for debugging, however, there is 15+ components, so sharing all would be a mess :(

I have not though about that scenario before regarding the returns of the data. I will take a quick look for this!
-- Edit; I have returned all my data functions as objects.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue reported on a old android device, here's what i did :

We had components with both `mapActions(["something"])` and a defined method `something() { this.$store.dispatch('something') }`
So i removed the methods declaration.

It still didn't work so I check the build main.xxxx.js on eslint
and found some "Attempted to redefine property 'value'" on something like `domProps:{value:t.value,value:t.value}`
Looked up the code and saw that we had components with both `v-model` and `:value` and also some checkbox using `v-model` and `:checked`.
I only kept the `v-model` and it works.

It also seems like the problems could come from repeated props like stated here : https://www.tutorialfor.com/blog-267252.htm

Comment: Kudos for taking you the time to explain this for feature people.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a restriction that was only in effect in ES5 strict mode, which these environments you have apparently use. It absolutely makes sense but was nonetheless loosened in ES6 because of computed properties - see [What's the purpose of allowing duplicate property names?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30617139/1048572) for details. That's why babel doesn't complain about it when transpiling.

To find these (valid but nonsensical) duplicate property names in object literals in your code base, you can use a linter [such as ESLint](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-dupe-keys) with a rule against these.

Comment: This is is a really great answer for the question! If I had not luckily found the line as I did, this would be perfect solution to find the issue!