# Only one string allowing in minimist?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Below is the out I get from the code that is also below.

**Question**

`input` and `i` are both true, as expected, but why isn't `project` and `p`?

They are defined that exact same way as `input` and `i`.

```
$ bin/test --input -p           
{ _: [],
  update: false,
  u: false,
  input: true,
  i: true,
  p: '',
  project: '' }
```

And the code is

```
'use strict'
var minimist = require('minimist')

module.exports = () => {
var argv = minimist(process.argv.slice(2), {
  string: 'input',
  string: 'project',
  boolean: ['help'],
  boolean: ['update'],
  alias: { i: 'input', h: 'help', p: 'project', u: 'update' },
  unknown: function () { console.log('Unkown argument') }
})

  if (argv.input || argv.i) {
    console.log(argv)
  }

  if (argv.project || argv.p) {
    console.log(argv)
    console.log('p')
  }
```

Comment: You cannot have an object with two `.string` properties and two `.boolean` properties. Your linter should have complained about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have duplicate property names in an object (unfortunately [they are allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30617139/1048572), not throwing exceptions any more).

Your current code is equivalent to

```
var argv = minimist(process.argv.slice(2), {
  string: 'project',
  boolean: ['update'],
  alias: { i: 'input', h: 'help', p: 'project', u: 'update' },
  unknown: function () { console.log('Unkown argument') }
})
```

where `input` is not defined as a string parameter but `project` is.

What you want to write is

```
var argv = minimist(process.argv.slice(2), {
  string: ['input', 'project'],
  boolean: ['help', 'update'],
  alias: { i: 'input', h: 'help', p: 'project', u: 'update' },
  unknown: function () { console.log('Unkown argument') }
})
```